# android tv setting focus transition speed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-tv

I have an tv app. I have a lot of views in main screen. I want to set speed of focus when I keep pressed the down button. It's so fast normally. I want to slow down of focus transition inter views.

How can I do that?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a key throttle implementation. This can be done using `setOnKeyInterceptListener`. Lets say in the scenario where you are using `verticalGridView` (or any other leanback viewGroup with an option to add the intercepter:

```kotlin
private fun setKeyInputThrottle() {
    verticalGridView?.setOnKeyInterceptListener { keyEvent ->
        val systemTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        when {
            keyEvent.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                keyLastInputTimestamp = null
                false
            }

            keyLastInputTimestamp == null -> {
                keyLastInputTimestamp = systemTime
                false
            }

            keyLastInputTimestamp != null &&
                systemTime - keyLastInputTimestamp!! > KEY_THROTTLE_TIME_MILLIS -> {
                keyLastInputTimestamp = systemTime
                false
            }

            else -> true
        }
    }
}
```

This will work with a local timestamp instance and a constant Throttle you can set. My optimal configuration currently:

```kotlin
companion object {
    const val KEY_THROTTLE_TIME_MILLIS = 100L
}

private var keyLastInputTimestamp: Long? = null
```

Feel free to improve this code if it makes sense.